# Какую роль играют имена классов перед аргументами функций и методов?

Tags: php, ооп

Вт к примеру кусок кода:

```
namespace App\Bot;

use App\WordPress\Functions as WordPressFunctions;

class Base
{
    private $logger;
    private $wp_facade;

    public function __construct($logger, WordPressFunctions $wp_facade)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->wp_facade = $wp_facade;
    }
}
```

для чего в данном случае

> WordPressFunctions

перед

> $wp_facade

Кому какая польза от этого ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это так называемый type hinting - контроль типа для входящего параметра. Если в класс будет передан параметр не того типа, как указано перед параметром, то получите ошибку.